# reset NR in awk

Tags: awk, ash

`cat file.txt`

```
MNS GYPA*N  
MNS GYPA*M  c.59T>C;c.71A>G;c.72G>T
MNS GYPA*Mc c.71G>A;c.72T>G
MNS GYPA*Vw c.140C>T
MNS GYPA*Mg c.68C>A
MNS GYPA*Vr c.197C>A
MNS GYPB*Mta    c.230C>T
MNS GYPB*Ria    c.226G>A
MNS GYPB*Nya    c.138T>A
MNS GYPA*Hut    c.140C>A
.
.
.
```

the second column values could start with GYPA,GYPB,GYPC,GYPD, ... GYPZ. I would like to set a position count for each GYP* and split the third column as follows:

```
1   MNS  GYPA*N
2   MNS GYPA*M  c.59T>C
2   MNS GYPA*M  c.71A>G
2   MNS GYPA*M  c.72G>T
3   MNS GYPA*Mc c.71G>A
3   MNS GYPA*Mc c.72T>G
4   MNS GYPA*Vw .140C>T
5   MNS GYPA*Mg c.68C>A
6   MNS GYPA*Vr c.197C>A
1   MNS GYPB*Mta    c.230C>T
2   MNS GYPB*Ria    c.226G>A
3   MNS GYPB*Nya    c.138T>A
4   MNS GYPB*Hut    c.140C>A
.
.
.
```

cat `format.awk`

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}

$2 ~ /GYPA/
   { num=split($3,arr,/;/);
      for (i=1;i<=num;i++)
         { print NR,$1,$2,arr[i]}}

$2 ~ /GYPB/
   { num=split($3,arr,/;/);
      for (i=1;i<=num;i++)
         { print NR,$1,$2,arr[i]} }
...
```

I am not sure how to reset NR when it reaches the the next ~ GYP. The GYP{A..Z} are in order from A to Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
{
  match($2,/[^*]*/)
  gy_value=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
gy_value!=prev_gy_value{
  count=0
}
!arr[$2]++{
  count++
}
{
  num=split($3,array,";")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print count,$1,$2,array[i]
  }
}
NF<3;
{
  prev_gy_value=gy_value
}
' file.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  match($2,/[^*]*/)                     ##Using match function to match till * in 2nd field.
  gy_value=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Creating variable gy_value which has sub-string of 2nd field sub-string in it.
}
gy_value!=prev_gy_value{                
  count=0                               ##Creating variable count as 0 here.
}
{
  count++                               ##Increasing value of count with 1 here.
}
{
  num=split($3,array,";")               ##Splitting 3rd field into an array with delimiter ; and its count is stored into num variable.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                  ##Starting for loop from i=1 to till value of num here.
    print count,$1,$2,array[i]                ##Printing value of $1,$2 and array with index variable i here.
  }
}
NF<3;                                   ##Checking condition if NF<3 then print the line here.
{
  prev_gy_value=gy_value                ##Setting value of variable gy_value to variable named prev_gy_value here(which is used above code to make sure about values check).
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: What does !a[$2]++ do?

Comment: @user171558, its checking if 2nd field is NOT already present in array a then only go inside {..} to increase variable count's value, please do give me few mins will add detailed explanation too in my solution.

Comment: @user171558, Detailed explanation is added now, please go through it.

Comment: By redefining `$1` you recalculate `$0` and all fields. This might have unwanted effects. It might be better, just to say `print count,$1,$2,array[i]`, this avoids this conundrum.

Comment: @kvantour, Sure I have added the solution now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to reset `NR` when it reaches the the next ~ `GYP`. The `GYP{A..Z}` are in order from A to Z.

It is not possible to reset or change internal awk variables like `NR`, `FNR` or `NF`. These values are set by awk. The easiest is to keep track of an alternative `NR` as a variable which can can name `c` or anything else. This value can be reset under any condition to any value you want.

Example: Have a counter that resets to one every time it sees `foo` in a record:

```
awk '{c++}($0 ~ /foo/){c=1}{print c,$0}'
```

In case of the OP, something like this might be used:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     {c++; key=substr($2,1,index($2,"*")-1)}
     (key != key_prev) { c=1 }
     { prefix="" }
     (key == "GYPA") { prefix="NM_002099.7:"}
     { num=split($3,a,";"); for(i=1;i<=num;++i) print c,$1,$2,prefix a[i] }
     { key_prev=key }' file
```